# Debugging an Application by using a remote phone

Tags: android, remote-control

Is there a way to debug my android app on a remote phone?

For example if there is a program supports accessing remote computer's USB device so I can debug my app on a device connected to this computer?

Or if there is an android application which supports debugging directly to a remote phone.

Comment: why not install android studio on remote pc and debug there itself.

Comment: I don't want to transfer my code

Comment: how about writing necessary logs to textfile and getting that file from phone directly. no need to even connect to pc.

Comment: I have a log file but with my situation it is not enough.

Comment: then it looks like a difficult situation.

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use firebase crashlytics for remote debugging

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics